# Python 3: Append keeps iterating over letters of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file of keywords that are tab delimited.  I want to create a reference list of each instance of a keyword, therefore it would duplicates should the need arise.  I can print each keyword, but when I try to append the keyword to the list, it iterates over the string and adds each letter instead of the entire word.  How do I get the entire word to append?

I have already tried:

```
    ref_count.insert(0,item)
    ref_count[:0] = [item]
    ref_count = ref_count + [item]
    ref_count.extend(item)
```

Here is my code:

```
    import os
    import operator
    from collections import Counter

    ref_count=[]
    with open('Keyword_Lists/1991-2001.txt','r') as ref:
      for line in ref:
        for item in line.strip().split('\t'):
          if item == '':
            pass
          else:
            ref_count.append(item)

    print(ref_count)
```

This produces: `['A', 'T', 'H', 'L', 'E', 'T', 'E', 'S', '\t', 'D', 'I', 'S', 'T', 'A', 'N', 'C', 'E', 'S']`

However, when I `print(item)` it prints

```
    ATHLETES
    DISTANCES
    etc.
```

What am I doing wrong?  I need the entire word to be an element of the list.

EDIT: I figured it out.  I was importing packages that were interfering with the desired outcome.  I removed `import os`, `import operator`, and `from collections import Counter` and that fixed my problem.  Not sure why those were affecting my iterations.

Comment: Can you provide exactly the code that produces `['A', 'T', 'H', ...]`? The code block you have now doesn't have any print statements, so it shouldn't be producing anything.

Comment: @Kevin I'm assuming they are referring to the contents of `ref_count`.

Comment: I don't like to make assumptions when I'm looking at code that should produce good output, and isn't. A [mcve] is never more important than when you're getting seemingly impossible results.

Comment: @Kevin Yes, looking at it now OP's code should work.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include `the print(ref_count)`